# Passing $_ item from a string collection into a function called from Select-Object

Tags: powershell, select-object

Okay... so I have a System.Data.DataRow object. I've gotten the column names out into a string collection. Then I want to get the corresponding values into a second collection.

I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb here, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.
Take the following code...

```
$cols = $drFrom.Table.Columns
$colNames = $cols | Where-Object { $_.ColumnName -ne "ROWID" } | Select-Object $_.ColumnName
Write-Host $colNames
$colValues = $colNames | Select-Object $drFrom.Item($_).ToString()
```

Note that the `Write-Host` is showing that `$colNames` contains the expected column names, and outputs this in the console:

```
CLIENTID MESSAGE AMOUNT PAIDBY PAIDBYEMAIL ACTIVE
```

So the intention then is to pipe `$colNames` into `Select-Object`, and for each column name, get the value from the DataRow. But for some reason, when it's running through the `Select-Object`, `$_` seems to be returning as empty, instead of the string values that are known to exist in the `$colNames` collection. When it runs the 4th line, to do the piping, it throws this exception:

```
Exception getting "Item": "Exception calling "get_Item" with "1" argument(s): "'column' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: column""
At D:\MyScripts\MyScript.ps1:145 char:5
+     $colValues = $colNames | Select-Object $drFrom.Item($_).ToString( ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], GetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseParameterizedPropertyAdapterGetValue
```

I've also tried embedding the iteration variable in quotes, like so...

```
$colValues = $colNames | Select-Object $drFrom.Item("$_").ToString()
```

Then the exception changes accordingly, but still reflecting a value of empty for `$_`:

```
Exception getting "Item": "Exception calling "get_Item" with "1" argument(s): "Column '' does not belong to table .""
+     $colValues = $colNames | Select-Object $drFrom.Item("$_").ToStrin ...
```

How do I get the iteration variable to actually reflect the string values that are in `$colNames` when piping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamically define *properties* via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object), you must use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), which involve a hashtable that defines a property *name* and a *script block* (`{ ... }`) that defines the property *value*, in which you can refer to the pipeline input object at hand via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).

However, you're not looking to define a calculated *property*, you're looking to output a calculated *value*, and for that you need to use a call to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```
$colNames = $cols | 
              Where-Object ColumnName -ne ROWID |
                ForEach-Object ColumnName

$colValues = $colNames |
               ForEach-Object { $drFrom.Item($_).ToString() }
```

Note that the first pipeline uses [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax), both for the  `Where-Object` and the `ForEach-Object` call.

Comment: Switching from `Select-Object` to `ForEach-Object` was the ticket; thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @eidylon; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I want to get the corresponding values into a second collection.

And you have:

```
$cols = $drFrom.Table.Columns

$colNames = $cols | 
    Where-Object { $_.ColumnName -ne "ROWID" } | 
    Select-Object $_.ColumnName
```

Which works (but could be simplified).

Now there are 2 things you want to do:

- Select columns
- Convert columns to strings

It's much simpler to do these separately.

First select the properties you want:

```
$colValues = $drFrom |
    Select-Object $colNames
```

Now you have the columns you want in a PSCustomObject. This is important because we can use the hidden PSObject property:

```
$colValues.PSObject.Properties.Name |
    ForEach {$colValues.$_ = [string]$colValues.$_}
```

Here I've switched from calling .ToString() to using the cast operator, [string], because it handles $null without error.

I think that will give you what you want.

Your calculation of column names could be simplified to

```
$colNames = drFrom.Table.Columns.ColumnName | 
    Where-Object {$_ -ne "ROWID"}
```

If there is any possibility drFrom is a list, then:

```
$colNames = drFrom[0].Table.Columns.ColumnName | 
    Where-Object {$_ -ne "ROWID"}
```

When you just want to eliminate columns, which seems to be the case, you can simplify to:

```
$colValues = $drFrom |
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty "ROWID"
```

And convert remaining properties to strings:

```
$colValues.PSObject.Properties.Name |
    ForEach {$colValues.$_ = [string]$colValues.$_}
```

When you write:

> I want to get the corresponding values into a second collection.

It's not clear in what form you want that collection. Above I generated an object with named properties because I find that's more usable in PowerShell. The code you provided seemed to be attempting to pull out a list of strings. If that's what you want, then replace the last code line above with:

```
$stringList = $colValues.PSObject.Properties.Name |
    ForEach {[string]$colValues.$_}
```

I hope this helps.